# Monodroid - Drag View with Touch event?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, touch, absolutelayout

I want to drag a view. Until now i tried it with a LinearLayout and margins and with a AbsoluteLayout.

AbsoluteLayout example:

```
button.Touch = (clickedView, motionEvent) =>
{
   Button b = (Button)clickedView;
   if (motionEvent.Action == MotionEventActions.Move)
   {                    
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(100, 35, (int)motionEvent.GetX(), (int)motionEvent.GetY());
        b.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;                    
   }
   return true;
};
```

In every case I tried I got a curios behaviour. Here's why. The view i'm dragging follows my finger but jumps always between two positions. One postition hits my finger the other is somewhere to my fingers left-top. If I'm just writing my current position into a textview (without moving the view) the coordinates behave as expected. But if i'm also moving the view they are jumping again.
How can i avoid this?

EDIT: I used sounds comment on my question to implement a working draging for monodroid (it is done for Java/Android SDK in the linked site). Maybe others are interested in doing that some day, so here's my solution:

```
[Activity(Label = "Draging", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class Activity1 : Activity
{
    private View selectedItem = null;
    private int offset_x = 0;
    private int offset_y = 0;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)FindViewById(Resource.Id.vg);
        vg.Touch = (element, motionEvent) =>
        {
            switch (motionEvent.Action)
            {
                case MotionEventActions.Move:
                    int x = (int)motionEvent.GetX() - offset_x;
                    int y = (int)motionEvent.GetY() - offset_y;
                    int w = WindowManager.DefaultDisplay.Width - 100; 
                    int h = WindowManager.DefaultDisplay.Height - 100; 
                    if (x > w)
                        x = w;
                    if (y > h)
                        y = h;
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent,
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent));
                    lp.SetMargins(x, y, 0, 0);
                    selectedItem.LayoutParameters = lp;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        };

        ImageView img = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.img);
        img.Touch = (element, motionEvent) =>
        {
            switch (motionEvent.Action)
            {
                case MotionEventActions.Down:
                    offset_x = (int)motionEvent.GetX();
                    offset_y = (int)motionEvent.GetY();
                    selectedItem = element;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        };
    }        
}
```

Comment: http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-beginner-tutorials/drag-and-drop-ui-element/